# What is the probability of pulling the word HERO using random {consonant}{vowel}{consonant}{vowel} using the English vowel set {a,e,i,o,u}?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of pulling the word $\mathbf{HERO}$ 
using random forum rolepay dices named:
**{consonant}{vowel}{consonant}{vowel}** 

using the English vowel set **{a,e,i,o,u}**
and the remaining being consonant ?

If it was pure letter being drawn using **{letter}{letter}{letter}{letter}**,
I would expect that to be:

$26^4 = 456976$

So would this means that in that case the probability of drawing HERO 
using **{consonant}{vowel}{consonant}{vowel}** is:

$21 \times  5 \times  21 \times  5 = 11025$

In some forum games, someone asked that question over here:
http://twd.io/e/-lsH0M/95

> How many posts were made trying to get to $\mathbf{HERO}$? Any mathematician here has enough free time to calculate how many left until we reach the $x$ in the $1$ in $x$ chances?

So, the probability would be $\frac{1}{11025} \approx 0.00009070294$ ?

However, the amount of tries required of forum posts to obtain exactly
$P(HERO)$ would tend towards infinity, since each try is discrete ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption is indeed correct; the probability would be $1/11025$, since the probability for $x$ independant events to occur is the product of the events individual probability.

Answer (score 0):

You have calculated *the number of possible combinations*, not the probability. However, the probability is just *one over the number of possible combinations*, so you have $$P(\text{HERO})=\frac{1}{11025} \approx 0.0001$$

That means you will *on average* have to make $11025$ rolls, but you could get it on your first try, or - in principle - never.